# PHP vs Django argument separators

Tags: php, django, arguments

I've been re-writing a Django server in PHP (I have plenty of reasons to do this), and have run into a problem with arguments via e.g. `$_REQUEST`.

Django expects arguments to be formatted as: `id=822;date_accepted=2011-03-30 17:33:41;` (this is what the clients use, so this is what I want to use).
However, PHP expects arguments to be formatted as: `id=822&date_accepted=2011-03-30 17:33:41;`.

So, when I read $_REQUEST in PHP, it comes out as: `"id" => "822;date_accepted=2011-03-30 17:33:41;"`, rather than: `"id" => "822", "date_accepted" => "2011-03-30 17:33:41"`.

Is there anyway to get the arguments separated correctly?

Comment: So,.. what are you asking us exactly right now? There's a question missing somewhere.

Comment: Both are valid according to http parameters rfc. So?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what are some of your reasons?

Comment: @zeekay I’m wary to answer that question if only just because it’s the internet, but I will satisfy your curiosity: I know almost nothing about web programming, but wrote the initial server in Django + piston because I know Python pretty well and people seem very fond of Django. However, maintaining our (relatively simple -- like 200 lines) server, I found Django to be overkill (it’s CRUD model doesn’t match our backing data), and opaque and confusing. I imagine it’ll be great when I actually have enough web dev under my belt, but for now it’s too much to learn all at once.

Comment: I can appreciate that. If you would rather use python you might find [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or another micro framework more suitable in that case.

Comment: I also like [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) a lot.

Comment: @PureForm: I’m tentatively picking @Galen’s answer, because it does work. That said, yours looks like it would be the "correct" solution, if it worked, so if you have any suggestions and I can get it to work, I’ll gladly change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding this to your `.htaccess` file?

`php_value arg_separator.input ";"`

Comment: There's no change. I should mention (in case it isn’t obvious), that I’m also doing a bunch of Rewrite* stuff in there.

Comment: Actually, I was confused! It *does* work! Man, I am such a noob at web-stuff. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

replace ; with & and run it through `parse_str`

```
$str = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];//id=822;date_accepted=2011-03-30 17:33:41;
parse_str( str_replace( ';', '&', $str ), $_GET );
print_r($_GET);
```

Comment: Hey, this works, though the brute-forcedness of it makes me sad. (Thanks, though!)

Comment: Ah, actually, this only works for a subset of my queries; `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is only occupied for GET requests.